# Application keeps crashing ,isolated storage

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, crash

For a long time I was using around 40 checkboxes and 40 buttons in one page. Each state of a checkboxes were saved in IO. I made another page with same amount of checkboxes and buttons so I thought a little bit about faster page loading. Suddenly... I used emulator and... my app crashes in 50% cases while launching this big page. (40checkboxes+40 buttons) I separated it to 4 pages (each for 10checkboxes+10 buttons) but problem keeps happening. I get error while launching this page for the second time.  Actually, in page 1 , there everything is ok.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException is the error
```

in line :

```
  cb11.IsChecked = cbStates(10)
```

This is the code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Controls
Imports System.Windows.Documents
Imports System.Windows.Input
Imports System.Windows.Media
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation
Imports System.Windows.Shapes
Imports Microsoft.Phone.Controls
Partial Public Class Weidersix2
    Inherits PhoneApplicationPage
    Private cbStates As List(Of Boolean)
    ' Constructor
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        cbStates = New List(Of Boolean)()
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(e As System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnNavigatedTo(e)
        cbStates = DB.readStates()
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cb11.IsChecked = cbStates(10)
            cb12.IsChecked = cbStates(11)
            cb13.IsChecked = cbStates(12)
            cb14.IsChecked = cbStates(13)
            cb15.IsChecked = cbStates(14)
            cb16.IsChecked = cbStates(15)
            cb17.IsChecked = cbStates(16)
            cb18.IsChecked = cbStates(17)
            cb19.IsChecked = cbStates(18)
            cb20.IsChecked = cbStates(19)
        Else
            If cb11.IsChecked = True Then
                cbStates.Add(True)
            Else
                cbStates.Add(False)
            End If
            If cb12.IsChecked = True Then
                cbStates.Add(True)
            Else
                cbStates.Add(False)
            End If
            If cb13.IsChecked = True Then
                cbStates.Add(True)
            Else
                cbStates.Add(False)
            End If
            If cb14.IsChecked = True Then
                cbStates.Add(True)
            Else
                cbStates.Add(False)
            End If
            If cb15.IsChecked = True Then
                cbStates.Add(True)
            Else
                cbStates.Add(False)
            End If
            If cb16.IsChecked = True Then
                cbStates.Add(True)
            Else
                cbStates.Add(False)
            End If
            If cb17.IsChecked = True Then
                cbStates.Add(True)
            Else
                cbStates.Add(False)
            End If
            If cb18.IsChecked = True Then
                cbStates.Add(True)
            Else
                cbStates.Add(False)
            End If
            If cb19.IsChecked = True Then
                cbStates.Add(True)
            Else
                cbStates.Add(False)
            End If
            If cb20.IsChecked = True Then
                cbStates.Add(True)
            Else
                cbStates.Add(False)
            End If

        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedFrom(e As System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnNavigatedFrom(e)
        DB.saveStates(cbStates)
    End Sub
    Private Sub cb11_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(10) = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub cb11_Unchecked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(10) = False
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub cb12_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(11) = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub cb12_Unchecked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(11) = False
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub cb13_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(12) = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub cb13_Unchecked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(12) = False
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub cb14_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(13) = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub cb14_Unchecked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(13) = False
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub cb15_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(14) = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub cb15_Unchecked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(14) = False
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub cb16_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(15) = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub cb16_Unchecked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(15) = False
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub cb17_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(16) = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub cb17_Unchecked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(16) = False
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub cb18_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(17) = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub cb18_Unchecked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(17) = False
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub cb19_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(18) = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub cb19_Unchecked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(18) = False
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub cb20_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(19) = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub cb20_Unchecked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If cbStates.Count > 0 Then
            cbStates(19) = False
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have that many states saved. Try changing your logic to:

```
       If cbStates.Count >= 20 Then
        cb11.IsChecked = cbStates(10)
```

You're trying to read a state that doesn't exist.